# How to catch authentication error in a login form partial in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, authentication, twig, fosuserbundle

Dear StackOverflow Community,

Currently I am implementing an authentication system in Symfony2 while using FOSUserBundle for my User Entity.

I have created a Twig partial containing the login form and I want to repeat that form. What is the best way to catch an authentication error globally, preferably without catching the error in the controller, since I want the form to work on every page of the application.

I found out that a session variable _security.last_error is set when the authentication has failed. Is there a hook in the framework I can use?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to separate catching authentication failure error messages from the controller, I have written a service.

Caught the exception using the following lines:

```
$authenticationUtils = $this->getContainer()->get('security.authentication_utils');
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
```

I have registered the service as a global twig variable, now i am able to reuse the login form partial without editing the controller responsible for the layout that contains the partial.